# Azure DevOps YAML - Pipeline resource shows inconsistent behavior with partially successful builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The problem i am running into is perfectly explained here, but at the time the user was pointed to another forum and no solution is written, if even available...

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/459

In short, my problem is that I have defined a pipeline resource in a YAML Pipeline.

```
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MainRebuild
    project: ProjectName
    source: 'Main - Rebuild'
    branch: feature/DummySmokeTest     
    trigger:
      branches:
      - master
      - feature/DummySmokeTest
```

The trigger works great, if the MainRebuild completes as Successful or PartiallySucceeded, a new pipeline is triggered that picks up the right version and can download the right artifacts.

The problem is when queueing the pipeline manually. The default resource configured is "Last successful run", which is indeed what i am looking for.

[image]

Only my last run has a result of PartiallySucceeded.
When I do not touch the resource and trigger the build, the build will pick up the latest build with state successful, not the very latest PartiallySucceeded build.

One workaround I found is that when triggering the build manually, I can choose a "different" resource. The pipeline nicely shows me all the Successful and PartiallySucceeded builds and I can choose one. I can choose the latest and say Use the selected run, the pipeline will then also use that properly.

So that is a workaround, but I would like to fix the default behavior of the latest successful to include the partially succeeded builds.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Update 1:

This my Download build task

```
      # Download build and pipeline artifacts
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: ProjectName
        pipeline: '$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.MAINREBUILD.PIPELINEID)'
        specificBuildWithTriggering: true
        buildVersionToDownload: specific
        buildId: '$(RESOURCES.PIPELINE.MAINREBUILD.RUNID)'
        allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true
        downloadType: specific
        itemPattern: |
          **\Installers\*.exe
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
```

Comment: Is it partially successful becasuse tests failed in the build?

Comment: could be for many reasons, not tests though, but one of the steps we allow to fail

Answer (score 0):

The docs for the `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` says you can use a option in the task to disable download of partially succeeded builds. I assume this is the task you are using to grab the artifact?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#arguments

> allowPartiallySucceededBuilds

> Download artifacts from partially succeeded builds (Optional) If checked, this build task will try to download artifacts whether the build is succeeded or partially succeeded
> Default value: false

Comment: Yes i am indeed using that, and works will when triggered, but when manually queing the build it does not pick up partiallySucceeded builds

Comment: I guess for a manual run that picker is not affected by this option. Then again the option is `allowPartiallySucceededBuilds: true` meaning that it allows partially succeeded builds. Sorry I can't help further

Comment: And technically it does allow them, it just does not consider them under "latest successful"

Comment: Yeah interesting. I can only suggest trying something with `resources` and tags but I guess it makes any difference to the interactive UI anyway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource